# regex pattern for {aa=xx bb=yy} and {aa=xx}

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex pattern that can pick `{aa=xx bb=yy}` or `{aa=xx}`

This is what I am using in the code.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([{])(aa=\\S+)\\s*(bb=\\S+)?([}])");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are `action` and `data` there? And do you want to match those strings, or find out those patterns in a larger string?

Comment: Not really, what do you want to extract exactly (in fine)?

Comment: Can you define precisely what you want the regex to accomplish? From your description, my thoughts go to something like this: `"{(action=\\S+)(\\s(data=\\S+))?}"`

Comment: Have to say I'm highly confused by the close votes for "opinion based".  This isn't asking for opinions, it's asking for better solutions.

Comment: I have posted a solution. So the question is about finding a better way to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use named captures:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(?<k1>[^=]+)=(?<v1>[^\\s}]+)(?>\\s+(?<k2>[^=]+)=(?<v2>[^}]+))?}");
```

then you obtain keys and values in named groups (k1 v1 k2 v2).

Notice: putting the space in an optional group with the second key/value is better and avoid a test.

An other way if you have an undeterminate number of key/value pairs inside curly brackets:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\{|\\G)([^=\\s]+)=([^\\s}]+)(?:\\s*|})");
```

*(I assume that there are no spaces around the `=`, you can add them if needed)*

Comment: The second pattern seems appropiate for me but it gives error:-  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 36:
07-27 19:41:18.470: E/AndroidRuntime(30582): (?:\{|\G)([^=\s]+)=([^\s}]+)(?:\s*|})
07-27 19:41:18.470: E/AndroidRuntime(30582):                                     ^

Answer (score 0):

A minor improvement: you may leave out capturing groups with character classes for the purpose of escaping special characters: just use `\{` instead of `([{])` and `\}` instead of `([}])`.

Comment: fyi `{` and `}` don't need to be escaped either.

Comment: @anubhava actually `{` should be escaped, but `}` can be used normally.

Comment: @Pshemo: THanks, yes just recalled that `{` needs to be escaped but not `}`

Comment: I get compile error when I remove the [{] to \{. my current pattern is   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([{])(aa\\s*=\\s*\\S+)\\s*(bb\\s*=\\s*\\S+)?([}])");

Comment: @user2465439: you probably tried to use a single slash in Java string literal. You need to escape backslash with another backslash *for Java*, e.g. `Pattern.compile("\\{...")`. This *Java string literal* is interpreted as the string `\{...` *by Java compiler*, and Regex engine sees only a single slash.

Comment: thanks, regex becomes \\{(aa\\s*=\\s*\\S+)\\s*(bb\\s*=\\s*\\S+)?\\}. any other improvements?